# how to suplay data in vb net the dataset with stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, datagridview, dataset

I  made code vb net, to can display in my form , I call data using dataset, my coding like below

```
Public Function GetTableRow(ByVal strsql As String) As DataSet

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection
        Dim sDa As New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Try
            sDa.Fill(ds)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        sDa.Dispose()
        Return ds
    End Function


    Private Sub CmRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmRefresh.Click

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim conn = "server='server'; database='database'; user=user;password='password';"
        Dim strsql As String = "exec spSPDMonStockProductHarian '" & 230 & "'"
        ds = conn.GetTableRow(strsql)

 With Listdata
            .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        End With
        Koneksi.Close()
        Koneksi.Close()
    End Sub
```

My problem when I execute this program, error message

```
"Public member 'Function' on type 'String' not found."
```

I didn't get what the problem , so any solution will appreciate!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```
    Private Sub CmRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmRefresh.Click

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim conn As String = "server='server'; database='database'; user=user;password='password';"
        Dim strsql As String = "exec spSPDMonStockProductHarian '" & 230 & "'"
        ds = GetTableRow(strsql)

        If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            With Listdata
                .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            End With
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Dataset is empty")
        End If
        Koneksi.Close()
        Koneksi.Close()
    End Sub
```

The changed i made here:

`Dim conn As String`
and
`ds = GetTableRow(strsql)`

Basically, `GetTableRow` is your custom function it is not defined inside class `string`.

Comment: i get error message "Cannot find table 0.", can you help my problem??

Comment: Basically your query/SP returns nothing as a result so system is unable to find any table. I have added handling for that in code. Can you please check if you have data present against key 230 ?

Comment: i have key 230 from my data table, i want to call one table,so i call data table 230 in detailID.

Comment: can you please check if the SP returns a table in SQL Server ?